# Chaining Parallel Tasks to an End Condition or Error Condition

Tags: c#, exception, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to wrap my head around some of the syntax and structure for parallel tasks in C#, specifically around [chaining multiple tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537612.aspx) and [handling errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537614.aspx).

The specific sequence of steps I'm looking to create are:

- Spawn a parallel task and immediately return to the UI.
- In the parallel task:

  - Do `Process1()`
  - If `Process1()` completes without error, do `Process2()`
  - If `Process2()` completes without error, do `Process3()`
  - If all tasks complete without error, do `SuccessCondition()`
  - If any task resulted in an error, do `ErrorCondition()`

It's my understanding that I would create a `Task` and call `ContinueWith()` to chain more tasks, passing in a `TaskContinuationOptions` flag to determine when to do that continuation.  Additionally, that success/error conditions would fall through all of the continuations to the end.  So I'm currently trying this:

```
var task = new Task(() => Process1());
var task2 = task.ContinueWith(t => Process2(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
var task3 = task2.ContinueWith(t => Process3(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
var task4 = task3.ContinueWith(t => SuccessCondition(t), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
var task5 = task4.ContinueWith(t => ErrorCondition(t), TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnRanToCompletion);
task.Start();
```

It appears to be behaving as expected, except that within `ErrorCondition()` the instance of `t` doesn't appear to have an exception, even if I manually threw one from within, say, `Process2()`.  Looking at the MSDN article for handling exceptions, it says to do this:

```
try
{
    task.Wait();
}
catch (AggregateException ex)
{
    // Handle exceptions from a collection on ex
}
```

However, I tried that and it doesn't seem to have the exceptions there either.  Also, by calling `.Wait()` in the main thread like that, am I negating the parallelism and just blocking?  It appears that way in my tests.

So I guess my question is... What's the correct way to chain dependent tasks and handle an overall success/error condition here?  Or, how should exceptions thrown from within these tasks be properly caught, while still returning immediately to the UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to add a continuation to all of the tasks, 1-4, with the error handling case to allow an error in any of them to call that function.

For convenience you could create a method to add the same continuation to a collection of tasks.  Here's one (feel free to add others for the other overloads of ContinueWith as needed):

```
public static IEnumerable<Task> ContinueWith(this IEnumerable<Task> tasks
    , Action<Task> continuation, TaskContinuationOptions options)
{
    return tasks.Select(task => task.ContinueWith(continuation, options))
        .ToList();//important for this ToList to be here; 
    //we want the continuations to be added now, not when the result is iterated
}
```

This allows you to write:

```
var errorTasks = new[]{task, task2, task3, task4}
    .ContinueWith(ErrorCondition, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnRanToCompletion);
```

Error handling for tasks is made so much easier in C# 5.0 with `async` methods though.  It would allow you to transform your code into this:

```
public static async Task Foo()
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Run(Process1())
        await Task.Run(Process2())
        await Task.Run(Process3())
        SuccessCondition();
    }
    catch (SomeExceptionType ex)
    {
        HandleException(ex);
    }
}
```

This functions just as you would think it does as per your requirements, which is awesome.

Comment: Could this be even further simplified if I don't necessarily _need_ them to be separate `Task` instances?  Originally I'd tried to create a single `Task` and call `.ContinueWith()` a few times on that, but then the compiler told me I couldn't run it because `task` was a continuation, not an actual task.  Can I chain them together differently such that control passes through and into the error condition?

Comment: @David Not using the existing `ContinueWith` method.  You'd need to make your own (possibly built on top of `ContinueWith` that propogated errors differently.  Currently if you add a contiuation for `OnlyOnRanToCompletion` and the source task faults, the continuation isn't run (which is what you want) but it's also marked as successfully completed (which you don't want).  You would want it marked as faulted.

Comment: You beat me to it on the async/await bit.

Comment: @Servy: I definitely like the `async`/`await` approach for readability, and I'm using the latest so that's an option.  However, my `Process()`es return `void`.  The compiler doesn't seem to like that.  There's really nothing meaningful for them to return, they either complete or throw an exception.

Comment: @David That's fine.  Then just don't store the result in a variable.  I wasn't sure, so I had to pick blindly.

Answer (score 4):

Note that if you're using .NET 4.5 and can use async/await, you can do this much more cleanly:

```
    public async Task DoProcess()
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Run(Process1);
            await Task.Run(Process2);
            await Task.Run(Process3);
            SuccessCondition();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorCondition(ex);
        }
    }
```

If you launch this from the UI thread, SuccessCondition and ErrorCondition will occur on the UI Thread as well.  One functional difference here is that the exception you catch will not be an AggregateException; it will instead be the actual exception thrown during the awaited call that failed.